# How do I make a column vector into an array of strings?

Tags: matlab

How would one go about taking a column vector like this:

```
a = [1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8;9;]
```

and turning it into this:

```
'1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [undocumented built-in function `sprintfc`](http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/sprintfc-undocumented-helper-function/#sprintfc) to convert a numeric array to a cell array of strings like so -

```
sprintfc('%d',a)
```

Sample run -

```
>> a = [1;2;3;34;5;6;7;8;19;];
>> sprintfc('%d',a)
ans = 
    '1'
    '2'
    '3'
    '34'
    '5'
    '6'
    '7'
    '8'
    '19'
```

As an alternative, you can also use a combination of `num2str`, `cellstr` & `strtrim` -

```
strtrim(cellstr(num2str(a)))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use documented functions one possibility is:

```
a = 1:9;
t = textscan(sprintf('%d\n', a ), '%s', 'delimiter', '\n');
t = t{1}';

ans = 
    '1'    '2'    '3'    '4'    '5'    '6'    '7'    '8'    '9'
```